# Any overlap of feaures with demandbase with MCP

Tags: marketing-cloud, demandware

If we have Demand base to collect account info, is there a separate use case for marketing cloud interaction studio (personalization)

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an overlap in functionality. But an important aspect is that most features within Commerce Cloud are for logged-in customers (recognised). While tools like Interaction Studio also segment anonymous users.

I'm not saying you can not do it with SFCC, and that will require custom development if the standard "known" things of anonymous customers are not enough.